# SSRS Excel export does not open a drill-through link in pop-up window

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, ssrs-2014

I have several SSRS reports that contain drill-through links that open up a pop-up browser window on the site, which works fine.

I am using java script in the URL for the textbox action.  The problem is that when I export the report to excel it fails to open the pop-up window.  For a while I got an error message "Reference is not valid" after clicking on the link.  Other drill throughs that bring you directly to the report work perfectly.  Its when I use the Java in the URL for the pop-up window.

I recently started using IE again, so now instead of getting the above error "Reference is not valid", I am now getting the following messages:
[image]
I click "yes" and then I get a blank "View Downloads" window.

[image]

This is the javascript that I am using for my Drill-through action URL

```
="javascript:void(window.open('/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRS%20Library/Rx Transaction Detail.rdl&rv:ParamMode=Hidden&rv:Toolbar=None&rv:HeaderArea=None&rp:StoreKey=" + Fields!StoreKey.Value.ToString + " &rp:RxNumber=" + Fields!RxIdentifier.Value.ToString + "&rp:RefillNumber=" + Fields!RefillNumber.Value.ToString + "', 'RXOVERVIEW','width=1335,height=450,location=no'))"
```

Is there any way to be able to open a browser pop-up window from an Excel Drill-Through link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me very well:

```
=IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive=false, Fields!Link.Value, "javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!Link.Value & "','_blank'))")
```